# 'Cannot read property '$store' of undefined' or Function CollectionReference.doc()... during Firebase SignIn and SignUp on vuex

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuex

It took me a couple days to figure out what was the problem when Sign in/Sign Up in Firebase Authentication. It might be actually simple syntax issue and javascript asynchronous issue.

***Errors that throws:*** 'Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined'

***Else:*** 'Cannot read property '$store' of undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a problem in the code of this tutorial, which comes from the fact that the [`signInWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#sign-inwith-email-and-password) method returns a [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#user-credential) and not a [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User).

So, you just need to adapt the code as follows:

```
   login() {

    fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginForm.email, this.loginForm.password).then( function (userCredential) {

        const user = userCredential.user;

        this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
        this.$router.push('/navigation')
    }).catch(err => {
        this.errorMsg = err.message
    })
  },
```

---

Actually, with version 5.0.0 of the Firebase JavaScript SDK (released on May 8, 2018), `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` has changed: it returns a promise that resolves with a `UserCredential` while **it used** to return a `User` in the previous version, see https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Comment: UserCredential, wow I never thought that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I solved as follows:

```
   login() {

    fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginForm.email, this.loginForm.password).then( function (user) {

        this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
        this.$router.push('/navigation')
    }).catch(err => {
        this.errorMsg = err.message
    })
  },
```

The base code from vuegram project from [Savvy app](https://savvyapps.com/blog/definitive-guide-building-web-app-vuejs-firebase).
Firstly, it throws an error that is **'Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined'**.

Then I found some hint from stackoverflow as changing **javascript function() to arrow function**. But it didn't solve the whole process. It throws **undefined user info from firebase**. Then added following lines code from my old experience.

```
   login() {

    fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginForm.email, this.loginForm.password).then(() => {
        var user = fb.auth.currentUser;
        console.log("User id: ", user.uid)

        this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
        this.$store.dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
        this.$router.push('/navigation')
    }).catch(err => {
        this.errorMsg = err.message
    })
  },
```

Now you can see the fetched user's data on browser console.
[image]